# mysql select & jsonencode data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting all from 'locations' table in my database. The last echo doesn't give me any output. However, I added `echo=$x`in the mysql_num_rows loop and this gives me numbers 1-17. So this works apparently.
Also selecting all from another table works just fine. This must be something easy but I cannot figure it...

```
$myquery="SELECT * FROM `locations` 
ORDER BY ID DESC";
$query=mysql_query($myquery);

if(! $myquery){
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

$data=array();

for($x=0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++){
    $data[]=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo $x;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: that works. but won't solve the problem of json encoding it, or?

Comment: Write down the output you get from `print_r($data) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be this is an error due to mysql charset. So add it before your query

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
```

Comment: that causes: "Warning: mysql_set_charset() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given"

Comment: what is the second parameter you passed? $connection?

Comment: `mysql` functions allow you to omit the connection argument, it defaults to the last connection opened.

Comment: well I'm calling it $conn as in the next line it's $conn as well

Comment: put that first line after your mysql_connect

Comment: aha. your description wasn't clear first. updated version works.

Comment: so it means I need to figure something with the char sets when I put the stuff into the db. will do